Why Promise.race() make process exited
The code:
async function test() {
      console.log("start")
      await Promise.race([]);
      console.log("end");
}

test();

Running result:
start

And the process existed. Why was console.log("end") not executed?

Because there is no promises to race, therefore the promise from .race() is pending forever? I'm not sure what else you really expect here.

await Promise.race([]); , this would create a promise that waits for the first promise in the array to resolve or reject. Because the array is empty, it never resolves or rejects.
It causes program to pause execution after that statement and because of the the indefinite wait the console.log("end") statement is never reached

Also since test() is called from the top level and is not awaited, it will just return control to whatever terminal you called your source from. All the awaiting will happen in the event loop, but that is going to be essentially running as a background process which will still be piped to the terminal you started it from

So even if you had promises in the array passed to Promise.race(), the script will exit without waiting for them. You'll never see end.

@Barmar If there is are promises, it will print end, I tested.

Depends on whhow long they take to resolve. If you test with, say, Promise.resolve() or anything that resolves in few milliseconds, then you'd get the end. But if the promise is long-living and nothing else keeps the Node process running then eventually Node would decide the promise will never fulfil. It won't wait for it to settle forever.

@VLAZ I expected it to be pending for ever, not automatically exited.

@VLAZ OK I understand a little bit. ChatGPT told me that await Promise.race([sleep()]) will be immediately finished, so I asked this question. I think I was misled by it.

It definitely won't finish immediately. Depends on what sleep() returns but if it's non-promise it'd still wait at least one tick (because Promise.race() is going to be fulfilled asynchronously). And if it's a completed promise - it'd still take at least one tick. await is never immediate. If it was, then you've unleashed Zalgo https://blog.ometer.com/2011/07/24/callbacks-synchronous-and-asynchronous/ https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony/ https://bluepnume.medium.com/intentionally-unleashing-zalgo-with-promises-ab3f63ead2fd
